# How to prohibit bang operator in Dart Linter / Pull request

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety, linter

Is it possible to fail a pull request pipeline if the developer has used the **"Bang Operator"** ?

We are using dart linter already in our PR pipeline, is there such a rule to enforce the prohibition of the **Bang Operator** ?

For example, this should not be allowed

```
Deal deal = widget.deal!
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add that check if you integrate [dart-code-metrics](https://github.com/dart-code-checker/dart-code-metrics) (package) to your pipeline. They have that specific rule available `avoid-non-null-assertion` , see it [docs here](https://dartcodemetrics.dev/docs/rules/common/avoid-non-null-assertion).

You can install it as an extension to the regular analyzer, so everyone gets the rules enforced at development time. And its also available as a CLI for using in a pipeline.

Codemagic recently added it as an option for their builds if you're using that.